# How to add a header to a csv file in Python?

Tags: python, csv

I've tried many solutions to add a header to my csv file, but nothing's working properly. Here they are :

1. I used the writerow method, but my data are overwriting the first row.
2. I used the DictWriter method, but I don't know how to fill it correctly. Here is my code:

   ```
   csv = csv.DictWriter(open(directory +'/csv.csv', 'wt'), fieldnames = ["stuff1", "stuff2", "stuff3"], delimiter = ';')
   csv.writeheader(["stuff1", "stuff2", "stuff3"])
   ```

I got a "2 arguments instead of one" error and I really don't know why.

Any advice?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

All you need to do is call [`DictWriter.writeheader()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter.writeheader) without arguments:

```
with open(os.path.join(directory, 'csv.csv'), 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = ["stuff1", "stuff2", "stuff3"], delimiter = ';')
    writer.writeheader()
```

You *already* told `DictWriter()` what your headers are.

Comment: Umm - is `t` a valid `open` mode ?

Comment: @JonClements: I didn't pay attention to the mode; just copied from the OP. Corrected.

Comment: TypeError: 'fieldnames' is an invalid keyword argument for this function, I'm using Python 2.6 , PyQt4.7. Can you help?

Comment: @Aleksandar: `fieldnames` is a keyword argument for the `csv.DictWriter()` and `csv.DictReader()` classes *only*. Make sure you don't confuse this with `csv.writer()` or `csv.reader()`. Python 2.6 supports it just fine, if you use it correctly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ok, thank you, I've tried it like in your answer and get `AttributeError: DictWriter instance has no attribute 'writeheader'`

Comment: @Aleksandar: Right, *that* Python 2.6 doesn't support. The method was added in Python 2.7. You can simulate it with `writer.writerow(dict(zip(writer.fieldnames, writer.fieldnames)))`.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar problem when writing the CSV file.
I had to read the csv file and modify some of the fields in it. 
To write the header in the CSV file, i used the following code:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open(infile))
headers = reader.fieldnames

with open('ChartData.csv', 'wb') as outcsv:
    writer1 = csv.writer(outcsv)
    writer1.writerow(headers)
```

and when you write the data rows, you can use a DictWriter in the following way

```
writer = csv.DictWriter(open("ChartData.csv", 'a' ), headers)
```

In the above code **"a"** stands for **appending**.

In conclusion - > use **a** to **append** data to csv after you have written your header to the same file

Comment: Why create a separate `csv.writer()` first, then open the *same file* for appending to with a `csv.DictWriter()`? Just use `writer = csv.DictWriter(outcsv, fieldnames=headers)`, then `writer.writeheader()`.