# Pythonically add header to a csv file

Tags: python, csv, header

I wrote a Python script merging two csv files, and now I want to add a header to the final csv. I tried following the suggestions reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907200/how-to-add-a-header-to-a-csv-file-in-python) and I got the following error: `expected string, float found`. What is the most pythonic way to fix this?

Here is the code I am using:

```
import csv

with open('combined_file.csv', 'w', newline='') as outcsv:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outcsv, fieldnames = ["Date", "temperature 1", "Temperature 2"])
    writer.writeheader()

    with open('t1.csv', 'r', newline='') as incsv:
        reader = csv.reader(incsv)
        writer.writerows(row + [0.0] for row in reader)

    with open('t2.csv', 'r', newline='') as incsv:
        reader = csv.reader(incsv)
        writer.writerows(row[:1] + [0.0] + row[1:] for row in reader)
```

Comment: how many columns are you writing into your csv file? Could you please specify in your question 1. input format of your file 2. output format

Comment: @nio: A large section of the code posted is from [this previous question by the OP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306550/python-merging-of-csv-files-with-one-axis-in-common)

Answer (score 167, accepted):

The `DictWriter()` class expects *dictionaries* for each row. If all you wanted to do was write an initial header, use a regular `csv.writer()` and pass in a simple row for the header:

```
import csv

with open('combined_file.csv', 'w', newline='') as outcsv:
    writer = csv.writer(outcsv)
    writer.writerow(["Date", "temperature 1", "Temperature 2"])

    with open('t1.csv', 'r', newline='') as incsv:
        reader = csv.reader(incsv)
        writer.writerows(row + [0.0] for row in reader)

    with open('t2.csv', 'r', newline='') as incsv:
        reader = csv.reader(incsv)
        writer.writerows(row[:1] + [0.0] + row[1:] for row in reader)
```

The alternative would be to generate dictionaries when copying across your data:

```
import csv

with open('combined_file.csv', 'w', newline='') as outcsv:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outcsv, fieldnames = ["Date", "temperature 1", "Temperature 2"])
    writer.writeheader()

    with open('t1.csv', 'r', newline='') as incsv:
        reader = csv.reader(incsv)
        writer.writerows({'Date': row[0], 'temperature 1': row[1], 'temperature 2': 0.0} for row in reader)

    with open('t2.csv', 'r', newline='') as incsv:
        reader = csv.reader(incsv)
        writer.writerows({'Date': row[0], 'temperature 1': 0.0, 'temperature 2': row[1]} for row in reader)
```

Comment: This works, funny thing: when file is opened in `a` mode, `writer.writeheader()` will write down the header twice despite of the header row was written already!

Comment: @loretoparisi: of course it does. Don't use `writer.writeheader()` when appending to an existing file. The `csv.writer()` object can't detect that you are writing data to an existing file.

Comment: Should check there are records to write before writing a header and only write header if at start of file.

Answer (score 14):

You just add one additional row before you execute the loop. This row contains 
your CSV file header name.

```
schema = ['a','b','c','b']
row = 4
generators = ['A','B','C','D']
with open('test.csv','wb') as csvfile:    
     writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=delimiter)
# Gives the header name row into csv
     writer.writerow([g for g in schema])   
#Data add in csv file       
     for x in xrange(rows):
         writer.writerow([g() for g in generators])
```

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me.

```
header = ['row1', 'row2', 'row3']
some_list = [1, 2, 3]
with open('test.csv', 'wt', newline ='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(i for i in header)
    for j in some_list:
        writer.writerow(j)
```

Comment: using file as a variable is not a good idea. Line #3. Use csvfile or some other instead.

Comment: @Gorgonzola It's just a syntax name in a StackOverflow answer... Could it be banana, but in this case it's just a file

Answer (score 2):

Would not this be simple that if we are creating file that time only we add header if we are not than append data to it..

```
  conso_file_path = 'your_folder_path\your_file.csv'
    # Create File
    if not os.path.exists(conso_file_path):
        print("No File")
        header = ['col_name 1', 'col_name 1', 'col_name 3', 'col_name4']
        with open(conso_file_path, 'w') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(header)
```