# How to fill new columns in a csv file through command line

Tags: python, csv

I have this text file:-

```
User_ID,Date,Num_1,Num_2,Com_ID
101,2015-04-13,12,21,1011
102,2014-04-03,1,7,1002
```

I am doing some basic manipulation in the input file and writing it back into the sample_output.txt file.

```
#!/bin/usr/python
import datetime
import csv
import sys
file_name='sample.txt'
with open(file_name,'rb') as f:               
    reader = csv.reader(f)  
    headers = reader.next()
    p=[]
    for row in reader:            
        row[0] = row[0].zfill(6) 
        row[2] = row[2].zfill(6)
        row[3] = row[3].zfill(6)
        row[4] = row[4].zfill(6)
        row[1] = row[1][5:7] + "-" + row[1][8:10] + "-" + row[1][:4]
        p.append(row[:5])
with open('sample_out.txt', 'wb') as ofile:     
        header = ['User_ID','Date','Num_1','Num_2','Com_ID','Dept','Location']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(ofile, fieldnames=header)
        writer.writeheader()
        col_fill = ''
        writer.writerows({col:row_item for row_item,col in zip(row+[col_fill]*n,header)} for row in p)
```

I need to add two new columns into the output file(sample_out.txt) and pass the values of those two columns via command line such that when I run the script:-
`python script.py BUS SAF` the output should be :-

```
User_ID,Date,Num_1,Num_2,Com_ID,Dept,Location
000101,04-13-2015,000012,000021,001011,BUS,SAF
000102,04-03-2014,000001,000007,001002,BUS,SAF
```

I can create the new columns.How do I fill the new columns by passing values via command line.

Comment: [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html)

Comment: sed '1! s/$/,BUS,SAF/' file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is very similar to your [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30658252/how-to-add-new-columnheader-to-a-csv-file-from-command-line-arguments/30658326#30658326) which I also answered... here I instead use the `argparse` library to give you input options to use like:

```
$ python pyscript.py -cl Dept Location -vl BUS SAF
```

you can also use like:

```
$ python pyscript.py --column_names Dept Location --fill_values BUS SAF
```

here is the code:

```
import argparse

# parse arguments from commandline if available
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-cl', '--column_names', default=None, nargs='+', type=str)
parser.add_argument('-vl', '--fill_values', default=None,  nargs='+', type=str)

extra_headers = parser.parse_args().column_names
col_fill = parser.parse_args().fill_values

# make sure col_fill is the same length as extra_headers    
if len(col_fill) == len(extra_headers):
    raise ValueError('Wrong number of column fills for number of headers!')
header.extend(extra_headers)

writer = csv.DictWriter(outcsv, fieldnames = header)
writer.writeheader()

# extend p with two columns of blank data
writer.writerows({col: row_item for row_item,col in zip(row+col_fill,header)} for row in p)
```

Comment: @satyaki - I also added in some error handling which you will probably need to avoid creating junk files by mistake. If my solution helped you could you please accept my answer and also on my [previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30658252/how-to-add-new-columnheader-to-a-csv-file-from-command-line-arguments/30658326#30658326)?

Comment: I am getting the output like this :- `User_ID,Date,Num_1,Num_2,Com_ID,python_poc1.py,-c,Dept,Location,-v,BUS,SAF
000101,04-13-2015,000012,000021,001011,BUS,SAF,,,,,`

Comment: what do you get when you add a `print col_fill` and `print extra_headers`? Also make sure you have changed `header` to `header=['User_ID','Date','Num_1','Num_2','Com_ID']`

Comment: I am not getting the what is happening in this line :- `writer.writerows({col:row_item for row_item,col in zip(row+col_fill,header)} for row in p)`.I have modified it a little to suit some formatting issues.Can you please breifly explain it.

Comment: the following docs will help you understand: [writerows](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#writer-objects) ; [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) ; [nested list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions)