# Write data to CSV file with column name using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I m using the below python code to write data to a CSV file with column name.

```py
def get_filename_datetime():
    # Use current date to get a text file name.
    return "Report-" + str(datetime.date.today())
# Get full path for writing.
filename = get_filename_datetime()
Data = [["FirstName", "LastName","Failed_User_Id"],
          [firstname, lastname, faileduserid]]
Reportfilename = os.path.join(reportspath, filename)
myfile = open(Reportfilename + '-Results.csv', "a+")
with myfile:
    writer = csv.writer(myfile)
    writer.writerows(Data)
```

I'm getting output in a file as:

[image: actual output]

My expected output is:

I'm getting output in a file as:

[image: expected output]

But I'm getting column name printed for each and every row.

Comment: can you please give the full code and output with screeshot or table structure

Answer (score 0):

That is because they are in the list `Data`:

```
Data = [["FirstName", "LastName","Failed_User_Id"],
                      [firstname, lastname, faileduserid]]
```

simply remove them:

```
Data = [[firstname, lastname, faileduserid]]
```

Examples of how to write header [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347766/pythonically-add-header-to-a-csv-file).

Comment: but i need  to give coulmn name to each coulmn

Comment: Just write it once before the loop, see the link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using method `get_filename_datetime` in loop, so you're keep appending this to the CSV file:

```
Data = [["FirstName", "LastName","Failed_User_Id"],
                      [firstname, lastname, faileduserid]]
```

Solution is moving column name outside of loop, append only row data:

```
 Data = [[firstname, lastname, faileduserid]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the headers repeated because every time you are adding a row you also adding the headers again You need to separate the first row in `Data` and write it once

```
def get_filename_datetime():
    # Use current date to get a text file name.
    return "Report-" + str(datetime.date.today())
# Get full path for writing.
filename = get_filename_datetime()
headers = ["FirstName", "LastName","Failed_User_Id"]     
Data = [firstname, lastname, faileduserid]
Reportfilename = os.path.join(reportspath, filename)
myfile = open(Reportfilename + '-Results.csv', "a+")
with myfile:
   writer = csv.writer(myfile)
   if(os.stat(myfile).st_size == 0):
      writer.writerows(header) 
    writer.writerows(Data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Both answers by @mtdot and @schoon are correct

**If you want to use pandas**

you can use this

```
`
columns = ['FirstName', 'LastName', 'Failed_User_Id']
header = True
for dataset in datasets:
    df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
    df = df[columns]
    mode = 'a+'
    df.to_csv('./new.csv', encoding='utf-8', mode=mode, header=header, index=False)
    header = False
`
```